# Python xmltodict shows inconsistent behaviour in XML arrays

Tags: python, xmltodict

I seen some, IMHO, inconsistent behaviour in Python xmltodoct.parse function.

- When an array has only 1 element, it returns an iterator with the child-elements
- When an array has more than 1 element, it returns an iterator with the elements in OrderedDict

See the example below:

```py
import xmltodict

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xml01 = """
            <A>
                    <C>
                        <D>DDDD</D>
                        <E>EEEE</E>
                    </C>
            </A>
    """

    xd = xmltodict.parse(xml01)
    print(xd)
    for x in xd['A']['C']:
        print(f"xml01: {x}")

    xml02 = """
            <A>
                    <C>
                        <D>DDDD</D>
                        <E>EEEE</E>
                    </C>
                    <C>
                        <D>DDDD</D>
                        <E>EEEE</E>
                    </C>
            </A>
    """

    xd = xmltodict.parse(xml02)
    for x in xd['A']['C']:
        print(f"xml02: {x}")
```

The output is:

```sh
xml01: D
xml01: E
xml02: OrderedDict([('D', 'DDDD'), ('E', 'EEEE')])
xml02: OrderedDict([('D', 'DDDD'), ('E', 'EEEE')])
```

I would expect that the output of the first iterator is:

```sh
xml01: OrderedDict([('D', 'DDDD'), ('E', 'EEEE')])
```

Now you need to do some type checking on the returned values of the iterator do know if there's one or more elements.
And with more elements you need to do a new loop.

I'm curious what Python experts are thinking of this and what their solution would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right.

And if you are asking my opinion, then I think it should be changed such to have `xml01` return a list with one child.

Though according to https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict/issues/14, the devs are aware of this but will not fix it.

The accepted workaround is to add `force_list` as a parameter to the parse, thus forcing a list of `OrderedDict` for the child element.

In your case, this would look like this:

```py
import xmltodict

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xml01 = """
            <A>
                    <C>
                        <D>DDDD</D>
                        <E>EEEE</E>
                    </C>
            </A>
    """

    xd = xmltodict.parse(xml01, force_list=set('C'))
    for x in xd['A']['C']:
        print(f"xml01: {x}")

    xml02 = """
            <A>
                    <C>
                        <D>DDDD</D>
                        <E>EEEE</E>
                    </C>
                    <C>
                        <D>DDDD</D>
                        <E>EEEE</E>
                    </C>
            </A>
    """

    xd = xmltodict.parse(xml02, force_list=set('C'))
    for x in xd['A']['C']:
        print(f"xml02: {x}")´
```

There is also a proposal to overwrite the `dict_constructor` to use `defaultdict`.

But you can browse this issue if that's the way you want to go with it.

Comment: Yes!!, that's the one. The Devs are not only not fixing it, they also don't take the trouble of adding "force_list" in the documentation on PyPI....